# Debian does not start any service at boot

Tags: ssh, debian, boot, service

I've got a VPS server running on Debian Wheezy and I monitor it with Zabbix. 
Yesterday, the server was unreachable, I could ping it but there was no ports open (using nmap). 
So I contacted the support which enabled SSHD manually but I had to restart all the services manually (Nginx, mysql, php-fpm, metronome, postifx, dovecot, etc).

I noticed with Zabbix, 15 minutes before everything became down, the kernel version changed from 2.6.32-34-pve to 2.6.32-37-pve. I checked syslog, debug, kern.log but nothing appears suspect. So, I don't know what happened. Today, I restarted the VPS, and same things happened.

Do you think the kernel update can cause that ? Any idea ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Is it starting in the correct run level?

Comment: according to /etc/inittab the run level is 1 I guess.              cat /etc/inittab
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

Comment: You have to check the `initdefault` line, the digit after the first colon indicates the default run level. You can check the actual current run level with `who -r` (or `ps -fp1` and check the digit between the brackets). This all assuming the good ol' init, not the newfangled systemd stuff. If it's 1, then it's not surprising that nothing was started as that's traditionally a sort of single user mode. Change it to 3, which is traditionally multi-user including daemons.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to change the run level to 3. I don't understand why it changed to one, I've never done any modification on it.

Comment: I tried but without success. It looks like ignoring all rc.d . I tried to put service ssh start on rc.local but it's not working

Comment: That is an ancient kernel. It looks like your provider updated it on you? (I'm running 3.2.0-4-amd64 w/ Wheezy, btw.) It looks like, based on the version, that your provider is running OpenVZ and something like https://github.com/proxmox/pve-kernel-2.6.32. That's not a bad thing, but if their new kernel changed the POSIX capabilities available to your container, then that would explain why things won't start. OTOH, if they DO start but don't stay started, that's a different problem.